# How to detect binary data in a file

Tags: shell, utf-8, grep

I have a file which should be a text file encoded in utf8.
However, when I try to use grep, grep report it as binary files.
For example:

```
$ grep ^ utf8.txt 
Binary file utf8.txt matches
```

However, I tried several methods to detect non-utf8 character in this file, and all of them failed.
For example, with iconv:

```
$ iconv -f utf8 -t utf8 utf8.txt -o utf8-2.txt
$ diff utf8.txt utf8-2.txt
$ sha256sum utf8.txt utf8-2.txt
eec16fc3fc4699000259b32e32ecd000684faa4075094031c1dfaaecae6a4654  utf8.txt
eec16fc3fc4699000259b32e32ecd000684faa4075094031c1dfaaecae6a4654  utf8-2.txt
```

By directly looking into the contents of that file, it seems to be a valid text file.
But grep treats it as binary files, and also the file command:

```
$ file utf8.txt
utf8.txt: data
$ file utf8-2.txt
utf8-2.txt: data
```

How to find the problematic characters in that file and fix them?

Note 1: I know that the option --text can force grep treat it as text file, but it is not what I want to do.

Note 2: For sure the file contains non-ASCII characters.

Final solution: Thanks to @lenz and @Mark Tolonen, with hexdump I find one null byte. After removing that byte, now the file is fine.

Comment: What does `grep -z ^ utf8.txt` say?

Comment: You can use `hexdump -C <FILE>` to inspect it. That is, if you're keen to look at hex numbers...

Comment: Does the file contain null bytes?

Comment: @Armali grep -z ^ utf8.txt will output the contents of that file.